# Is Honey, I Shrunk the Kids scaled correctly?

Tags: realism, honey-i-shrunk-the-kids

In the movie [*Honey, I Shrunk the Kids*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0097523/)(1989) the children are shrunk down to a tiny size. However, is everything scaled correctly (i.e, consistently)? For instance, when they ride the ant, are the ant and the children scaled correctly to the grass? Or the cigarette?

Comment: Not sure why this is attracting close votes...it seems a reasonable question to me.

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Headscratchers/HoneyIShrunkTheKids

Comment: Agreed.  This question is totally on-topic and I don't even know what to say about the "too broad" vote.

Comment: IIRC Rick Moranis' character says that the shrinking is done by removing some of the space in between atoms - this means the kids should weigh the same and would crush the ant.

Comment: _"... is everything scaled correctly?"_ - If you expect an answer to compare the scale of indeed ___everything___ that is shown, then this question is too broad.

Comment: @Mr_Thyroid so... Pym Particles?

Comment: It's a goofy comedy, and not meant to be hard-core science-based fiction. Not a fan of questions like this.

Answer (score 3):

> However, is everything scaled correctly (i.e, consistently)?

I don't think they scaled everything correctly.

From [***science of scale***](https://www.tor.com/2012/08/31/honey-i-shrunk-the-kids-and-the-science-of-scale/) :

> There is a logical contradiction between two claims made by the film:
>
> 1. Nick, the apparent scientist-in-training of the film, calculates
>      that they have been shrunk to just 3/4 of an inch high (around 19
>      mm).
> 2. As the movie progresses and the children go forth on their
>      tiny-sized adventures, one of the items they happen across is a toy
>      block, which Nick identifies as a “Lego.” However the scale of this
>      lego does not match the scale declared in the first statement.

[image]

> The Lego in question appears to be a standard 2×3 brick (Lego element ID 300223), which the protagonists use as a safe-haven before being attacked by a giant scorpion.
>
> If we assume that the block in the film is in fact a genuine Lego, and not some generic copy, the brick should be 23 mm tall when standing upright. Assuming Nick is in fact 19 mm tall as he claims, the brick he discovers in the film appears to be closer to 60 mm tall. This is about the size of a 2×8 brick, clearly not the one used in the film.

[image]

> The next discrepancy we looked at was the relative size of “Aunty,” the ant they tame and then subsequently use as a mount. While ant sizes vary, the one in the film appears to be a little over five times as long as Nick is tall. This would place the ant at a little over 100 mm long. Considering the largest ant currently known (the fossilized [*Titanomyrma giganteum*](http://primeval-fanon.wikia.com/wiki/Titanomyrma_%28NB%29)) was only 60 mm long, the ant in the film is unbelievably large.

Just a *note* from quora.

> The machine is described as removing much of the “empty space” between atoms. This means that you would become smaller and denser but not lighter! This creates lots of issues.
>
> 1. **You will suffocate**
> 2. **You would be nailed in place** (you may become small but still you weight the same)
> 3. **You would be blind or deaf**
> 4. **The process might make you explode exactly like the apples in the movie!**